# Laravel Eloquent Multiple updateOrCreate With Some Conditions

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm trouble with multiple update or create method on laravel.

My problem is simple;

I have a friendship table like this.

```
user_id_1, user_id_2, point
```

First of all;

I want to, give x points to 10 pieace of friendships.

But, if not exist friendship then create new friendship with x point.

if friendship is exists then update points to x point

I just need updateOrCreate function with where clause. And of course multiple inserting if supported like model::insert method.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Can you rephrase what it is you want to do, I'm having a hard time trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create is utilize pivot tables. Look at the many to many relationship in eloquent:

```
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many
```

You need to design a relationship between your users with an additional model or table. From there you could calculate points for a Point model.

EDIT (summary): So short of designing your entire schema and posting it (which is not how Stackoverflow is intended to be used), the answer to this would be that your pain point appears to be with eloquent as opposed to just restful functions.

Comment: @MuratGorken if this confuses you then I recommend going through some tutorials and reading up on eloquent (link above). For learning laravel try laracasts. This is pretty fundamental stuff.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a loop to find if the two users have already relation by verifying that the id of your first user == user_id_1 or == user_id_2 and the second user == user_id_1 or == user_id_2.
if the result is null then: no relationship between these users 
to update the relation you need just update the point column of your search result 
i will explain with a code example

```
$user_one=$request->id1;
$user_two=$request->id2;
$result= DB::table('your_table_name')->where(function($query) use ($user_one,$user_two){
$query->where('user_id_1',$user_one)
           ->orWhere('user_id_1',$user_two);})->orWhere(function($query) use ($user_one,$user_two){
    $query->where('user_id_2',$user_one)
           ->orWhere('user_id_2',$user_two);})->get();
    if(empty(result))
    {
    /* create your relation*/
    }
    else
    {
    /*update your point column with x*/
    }
```

Comment: Yep, thanks for reply. Just i can do it this way, but i want to handle this on single query. is it possibble?